# Highcharts donut customize legend

Tags: highcharts

[image]

How can I customize the legends in main series then its sub series like

```
Test
     Test1
    Test2
Demo
 Demo1
 Demo2
```

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? Using [`legendIndex`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<pie>.legendIndex) per point/slice you can control order of legend elements. To change position of each element you would have to extend Highcharts default function creating legend, so maybe you will be interested in creating a custom legend - examples: http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/, http://jsfiddle.net/stickerdude/1eg7yLmr/

Comment: Thanks Kacper. Please find my code in  jsFiddel  .https://jsfiddle.net/pankaj467/Lempxotg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `legendIndex` per data point / pie slice and in legend's labelFormatter you could change display based on what series is used.

Since you are parsing your data before using it in HC, don't forget to add `legendIndex` property for parsed data.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/10dbmwtf/

Comment: @Kacper Madej how can we change legend symbol to square or rectangle.

Comment: @Rohitesh You could use symbol options in legend. [Square](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/31e3m11y/), tall [rectangle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/31e3m11y/1/) and wide [rectangle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/31e3m11y/2/)